# How to avoid timeout for mocha asynchronous tests

Tags: selenium, protractor, timeout, mocha.js, assert

I have a mocha test that I am trying to run but it keeps on giving me the following error

Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called

```
it('should login into account', (done) => {
        let user_login = require("../../data/login.json");
        mongoManager.insertDocuments("user", user_login.content, () => {
            loginPage.setUserName('demodgsdg');
            loginPage.setPassword('123');
            loginPage.submit();
            browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
            Assert.equal(element(by.id('navbar')).isDisplayed(), true, "login page is not loaded");
            setTimeout(done(), 50000);
            done();
        });

    });
```

Whats the best way to run an asynchronous test in mocha so that it doesnt exceed its alotted time? Or should I set the timeout on the test function

Comment: What on earth is `setTimeout(done(), 50000)` supposed to accomplish? This will call the *return value of `done()`*, 50 seconds from now. Why? If you were calling `done` 50 seconds from now (the code would read `setTimeout(done, 50000)`, if that's what you were doing), that would make *some* sense, but calling the *return value* of `done()` makes no sense at all.

Comment: Umm setTimeout(done(), 50000) and just done(); are basically two different attempt to solve the issue highlighted above. The timeout event still occurs even without the "setTimeout(done(), 50000);" line. So for the sake of simplicity pls read the code assuming that setTimeout line doesnt exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it this way

```
it('should login into account', function (done) {
        this.timeout(50000);

        let user_login = require("../../data/login.json");
        mongoManager.insertDocuments("user", user_login.content, () => {
            loginPage.setUserName('demodgsdg');
            loginPage.setPassword('123');
            loginPage.submit();
            browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
            Assert.equal(element(by.id('navbar')).isDisplayed(), true, "login page is not loaded");
            setTimeout(done(), 50000);
            done();
        });
});
```

If you read https://mochajs.org/#timeouts

> Passing arrow functions (“lambdas”) to Mocha is discouraged. Due to the lexical binding of this, such functions are unable to access the Mocha context. For example, the following code will fail due to the nature of lambdas:

```
describe('my suite', () => {
  it('my test', () => {
    // should set the timeout of this test to 1000 ms; instead will fail
    this.timeout(1000);
    assert.ok(true);
  });
});
```

> If you do not need to use Mocha’s context, lambdas should work. However, the result will be more difficult to refactor if the need eventually arises.